# Memory leak in the implementation of the matrix multiplication operation

Tags: c++

Memory leak in the implementation of the matrix multiplication operation:

```
template <typename T>
    class Matrix
    {
    private:
        T *data = nullptr;
        size_t rows;
        size_t cols;
```

Here is the multiplication operation itself:

```
Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T> &other)
        {
            Matrix<T> result(rows, other.cols);
            if (cols == other.rows)
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    for (size_t j = 0; j < other.cols; j++)
                    {
                        for (size_t k = 0; k < cols; k++)
                        {
                            result.data[i * other.cols + j] += data[i * cols + k] * other.data[k * other.cols + j];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw std::logic_error("Matrix sizes do not match");
            }
            return result;
        }
```

How can I change this method so that it works correctly (and does not fall on tests)?

Here is a link to the class https://godbolt.org/z/4PPYx4Y3j. For some reason, everything works well here, but when I start doing a test:

```
TEST(testMatrixCalculations, testMultiplication)
{
    myMatrix::Matrix<int> mat1(3, 3);
    myMatrix::Matrix<int> mat2(3, 3);

    for (auto &it: mat1)
    {
        it = 3;
    }

    for (auto &it : mat2)
    {
        it = 3;
    }
    mat1.printMatrix();
    mat2.printMatrix();

    myMatrix::Matrix<int> mat3 = mat1 * mat2;
    mat3.printMatrix();
    for (auto it : mat3)
    {
        ASSERT_EQ(it, 27);
    }
}
```

Outputs this:

```
    3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
    3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
    -1119477653 32718 -1119477653 32718 775685387 21966 775685387 21966 27 
Failure
    Expected equality of these values:
      it
        Which is: -1119477653
      27
```

Comment: This code doesn't call `new`, so the leak is elsewhere. Can you make a [mcve] for us?

Comment: Your `operator*` doesn't allocate memory, so it cannot leak anything. Perhaps the issue is with copy constructor or copy assignment operator

Comment: As previous comments, no memory leaks here. Show the constructors and destructor methods of `Matrix` class.

Comment: Added a link to the class and the test itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `result.data` is not initialized to `0` but you apply a `+=` operation to it. You must either initialize your  `Matrix::data` member to zero in the `Matrix` main constructor function, or initialize it preliminary in your multiplication loop.

```
            for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

                for (size_t j = 0; j < other.cols; j++) {

                    result.data[i * other.cols + j] = 0;

                    for (size_t k = 0; k < cols; k++) {

                        result.data[i * other.cols + j] += data[i * cols + k] * other.data[k * other.cols + j];
                    }
                }
            }
```